# How do I use Zigbee to communicate to a laptop?

Tags: zigbee

What I have in mind is having a number of sensors (temperature, accelerometer, sound level meter) that are controlled by a micro controller. What I want to do is take this information and transmit it wireless to a laptop that will take this information and put it on to a web server using Zigbee. I don't know where to start.

Comment: Well, do you have existing hardware? An eval board maybe? If not, what are your requirements?

Comment: No I do not. I have done research on Zigbee and it seems like the proper protocol to use for what I need, but this is where I'm stuck. What sort of hardware do I need to take the sensor readings and communicate it to a laptop so I can monitor it? This is my first time trying to transmit data wireless. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Ruslik Thank you that would be helpful. (novusordo005@yahoo.com)

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have any hardware as of yet, you might want to give the [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) a try. The hardware is affordable, can be connected to your system via USB while being programmable in-system.

The basic board can be extended via so called "shields", which offer additional features. In your case, the [XBee shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoXbeeShield) would be appropriate. Connecting your laptop to a XBee module is as simple as using Sparkfun's [breakout board](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8687) and a mini-USB cable.

The Arduino has a large community, so you will find a lot of resources, like books, online material, example code etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Are there any other devices like the XBee shield that would allow me to transmit data wireless using Zigbee with other microcontrollers that is not part of the XBee line? Or perhaps you have other suggestions like using MiWi. Ultimately, I would like to have all my data put up on a web server. Thank you.

Comment: I would like to compare different devices that would allow me to transmit data to a laptop. Would I be searching for Zigbee Module/Bluetooth Modules/MiWi Modules or what would I be typing into a search engine? Does it depend on the micro-controller I'm using? I'm sorry if this seems really basic as I am very new to this.

Comment: Digi International (makers of the XBee radios) have an XStick USB adapter (http://www.digi.com/products/wirelessdropinnetworking/externalconnectivity/xstick.jsp) they also have a line of programmable XBee modules -- you can write code for an 8-bit Freescale chip alongside the radio IC on the module.

Answer (score 0):

We also provide wireless modules that can be used for serial data transmission. They can be found at [www.starmanelectric.com](http://www.starmanelectric.com) Our modules are very similar to the xbee, but more plug and play. They can be a great for going wireless for the first time. Our devices are designed to function like a "wireless cable" so if you're used to using wires then you'll be up and running in no time at all. We also have circuit examples for transmitting to a laptop serial port or USB. Any micro-controller will be fine for this application, as long as it has a serial port and a few ADCs to sample your data. Our modules also provide simple analog in/out which can run in parallel to the serial. If you want to compare to other systems, I would google "wireless serial modules"

Regards,

Michael

Starman Electric